# How can I define a concept that is satisfied by an arbitrary std::vector?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, c++20, c++-concepts

I would like to have a `concept` requiring an arbitrary vector as the return type:

```
template<typename T>
concept HasVector = requires (T t) {
    { T.vec() } -> std::same_as<std::vector<int>>; //works
    { T.vec() } -> std::same_as<std::vector<foo>>; //want to put something arbitrary in here
}
```

Such that we would have something like the following:

```
class A {
std::vector<int> vec() { /* ... */}
}

class B {
std::vector<double> vec() { /* ... */}
}

static_assert(HasVector<A>);
static_assert(HasVector<B>);
```

Moreover, it would be even nicer to require a vector as the return type whose value type satisfies some other concept, i.e.

```
template<typename T>
concept Arithmetic = // as in the standard

template<typename T>
concept HasArithmeticVector = requires (T t ) {
    { T. vec() } -> std::same_as<std::vector<Arithmetic>>;
```

Is there such a way to put this in names of concepts?

Comment: If only `template<typename T, concept C=Anything> concept HasVector = requires` could exist.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We start by writing a variable template to check if a type specializes a template:

```cpp
template <typename T, template <typename...> class Z>
inline constexpr bool is_specialization_of = false;

template <template <typename...> class Z, class... Args>
inline constexpr bool is_specialization_of<Z<Args...>, Z> = true;
```

Which we can turn into a concept:

```cpp
template <typename T, template <typename...> class Z>
concept Specializes = is_specialization_of<T, Z>;
```

Which we can then use to implement another concept:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept HasVector = requires (T t) {
    { t.vec() } -> Specializes<std::vector>;
};
```

If you want to then do further checking, that's just adding more requirements.

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept HasVector = requires (T t) {
    { t.vec() } -> Specializes<std::vector>;

    // or something along these lines
    requires Arithmetic<decay_t<decltype(t.vec()[0])>>;
    requires Arithmetic<range_value_t<decltype(t.vec())>>;
    // etc.
};
```

Comment: `Specializes` stretches the intended design rule for concepts; they are supposed to be describing a *concept*, not just testing syntax; and calling "this class specializes some other class" as a concept is a bit of a stretch.  No?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Also, `Specializes` (and the base `is_specialization_of`) cannot currently be made fully general.

Comment: @Deduplicator to be explicit, `Specializes<std::array>` won't work, and practically cannot.  You can do `SpecializesTs<std::vector>` and `SpecializesTA<std::array>` type stupidity.

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <concepts>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
concept Arithmetic = std::integral<T> || std::floating_point<T>;

template<typename T>
concept HasVector = requires (T t) {
  []<Arithmetic U, typename A>(std::vector<U,A> const&){}(t.vec());
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/eq5qdW6aa)

Comment: This might accept a type that has a conversion operator to vector<int>?

Comment: @MarcGlisse. No, that is [impossible](https://godbolt.org/z/d3sKx1cY4).

Comment: Uh, you are right. It does detect a class that derives from std::vector though (`struct Vec:std::vector<int>{};`).

Answer (score 1):

While I do like Barry's approach, I don't like that the solution imposes to be more generic than it actually is (it can't support templates that take any number of template parameters as well as non-type template parameters). Though, one easy way to prevent this is to make the concept customized to just vectors (e.g. `SpecializesVector`).

Another way to go about this, is to take advantage of the fact that all of `std::vector`'s template parameters are accessible through its publicly available member types `value_type` and `allocator_type`. Allowing us to write something like:

```
template<typename T>
using as_vector = std::vector<
    typename T::value_type,
    typename T::allocator_type>;

template<typename T>
concept vector = std::same_as<T, as_vector<T>>;

template<typename T>
concept has_vector = vector<decltype(std::declval<T>().vec())>;
```

And, if the we want the `value_type` of the vector be arithmetic, we could write something like this:

```
template<typename T>
concept arithmetic = std::integral<T> or std::floating_point<T>;

template<typename T>
concept arithmetic_vector = vector<T> and arithmetic<typename T::value_type>;

template<typename T>
concept has_vector = arithmetic_vector<decltype(std::declval<T>().vec())>;
```

While I also think that 康桓瑋's solution looks very neat and concise, using templated lambda's inside of a requires-clause actually makes potential error messages really unclear and hard to understand (which is supposed to be one the strong points of concepts). For example, when checking a type that has a member-function `vec()` which returns a `std::array` instead of a `std::vector`, the error messsage produced by Clang would be something like:

```
<source>:37:1: error: static assertion failed
static_assert(has_vector<D>);
^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:37:15: note: because 'D' does not satisfy 'has_vector'
static_assert(has_vector<D>);
              ^
<source>:25:5: note: because '[]<arithmetic U, typename A>(std::vector<U, A>) {
}(t.vec())' would be invalid: no matching function for call to object of type
'(lambda at <source>:25:5)'
    []<arithmetic U, typename A>(std::vector<U, A>){}(t.vec());
    ^
```

As opposed to:

```
<source>:37:1: error: static assertion failed
static_assert(has_vector<D>);
^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:37:15: note: because 'D' does not satisfy 'has_vector'
static_assert(has_vector<D>);
              ^
<source>:21:22: note: because 'decltype(std::declval<D>().vec())'
(aka 'array<int, 3>') does not satisfy 'arithmetic_vector'
concept has_vector = arithmetic_vector<decltype(std::declval<T>().vec())>;
                     ^
<source>:18:29: note: because 'std::array<int, 3>' does not satisfy 'vector'
concept arithmetic_vector = vector<T> and arithmetic<typename T::value_type>;
                            ^
<source>:10:1: note: because substituted constraint expression is ill-formed:
no type named 'allocator_type' in 'std::array<int, 3>'
```

And—while using the concept with the templated lambda—when we check a type with a `vec()` member-function that returns a `std::vector` that doesn't have an arithmetic `value_type`, we get the **exact** same error message as before:

```
<source>:36:1: error: static assertion failed
static_assert(has_vector<C>);
^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:36:15: note: because 'C' does not satisfy 'has_vector'
static_assert(has_vector<C>);
              ^
<source>:25:5: note: because '[]<arithmetic U, typename A>(std::vector<U, A>) {
}(t.vec())' would be invalid: no matching function for call to object of type
'(lambda at <source>:25:5)'
    []<arithmetic U, typename A>(std::vector<U, A>){}(t.vec());
    ^
```

As opposed to:

```
<source>:36:1: error: static assertion failed
static_assert(has_vector<C>);
^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:36:15: note: because 'C' does not satisfy 'has_vector'
static_assert(has_vector<C>);
              ^
<source>:21:22: note: because 'decltype(std::declval<C>().vec())'
(aka 'vector<char *>') does not satisfy 'arithmetic_vector'
concept has_vector = arithmetic_vector<decltype(std::declval<T>().vec())>;
                     ^
<source>:18:43: note: because 'typename vector<char *>::value_type'
(aka 'char *') does not satisfy 'arithmetic'
concept arithmetic_vector = vector<T> and arithmetic<typename T::value_type>;
                                          ^
<source>:7:22: note: because 'char *' does not satisfy 'integral'
concept arithmetic = std::integral<T> or std::floating_point<T>;
                     ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/concepts:100:24:
note: because 'is_integral_v<char *>' evaluated to false
    concept integral = is_integral_v<_Tp>;
                       ^
<source>:7:42: note: and 'char *' does not satisfy 'floating_point'
concept arithmetic = std::integral<T> or std::floating_point<T>;
                                         ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/concepts:109:30:
note: because 'is_floating_point_v<char *>' evaluated to false
    concept floating_point = is_floating_point_v<_Tp>;
                             ^
```

Answer (score -2):

As long as `vec()` is a public class method:

```cpp
template<typename T> struct is_vector { std::false_type operator()(); };

template<typename T, typename A> struct is_vector<std::vector<T, A>> {
    std::true_type operator()();
};

template<typename T>
concept HasVector = requires(T t) {
    { is_vector<decltype(t.vec())>{}() } -> std::same_as<std::true_type>;
};

class A {
public:
    std::vector<int> vec() {return {}; }
};

class B {
public:
    std::vector<double> vec() {return {}; }
};

class C {
};

static_assert(HasVector<A>);
static_assert(HasVector<B>);
```

Comment: That is a bad way to write a type trait (the convention is that `is_vector` inherits from `true_type` or `false_type`, not that it provides a call operator??) and that is a bad way to check a type trait (even with the call operator, you could just directly check the result, you don't have to go through this side-step of constraining the type to `true_type` - when the fact that it's `true_type` shouldn't even matter).

Comment: `is_vector` does not inherit from anything, or provides any call operator.

Comment: I'm aware that it doesn't inherit from anything - that's why I said that the convention is that it should. But what do you mean it doesn't provide any call operator - that's what your code does. It has a call operator. That's what `operator()` is.

Comment: To be more clear, @SamVarshavchik, your code *works* but it looks like a [tag:C++03] solution connected to a [tag:C++11] decltype solution grafted onto [tag:C++20] features.  And the [tag:C++11] style code isn't great; replace `{ std::true_type operator()(); };` with `:std::true_type {};`, for example.  But even if we cleaned up the [tag:C++11] part of your solution... if we have [tag:C++20], why not do it the cleaner [tag:C++20] ways anyhow?

Comment: Sure, inherit from `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`. Now on to the next step: using that in a concept, which now has to employ the services of `std::derived_from`. I don't see this to be a big improvement, in the end. And as far as C++20 syntax goes, I suspect that there might be folks who find this syntax to be too daunting/convoluted, and would prefer to use a more basic approach. I see nothing wrong with having this as an option.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik "... now has to employ the services of `std::derived_from`" No you don't. Have you never used a type trait before? You would just check `is_vector<T>::value`. Your answer isn't "more basic" - it's actually more involved.